# How to Enable(ON) Auto-increment (1,1) by using Migration on Id (primary) ? C#.NET(MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I Have tried the following codes Add-Migration EnableAutoIncerementToStudent.

but that code show no change in database.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You may use capital id - "ID" instead of just "id" which works perfectly for me. Otherwise, edit your table from the DB and alter the table with `identity(1,1)` in front of the id column.